# To chunk or not to chunk: How to control DocBook chunking with elements at the same level?

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

We are converting our documentation from a FrameMaker/ePublisher process to a DocBook XML process. The problem we have is that we cannot control the chunking in an easy fashion.

In our newly converted XML files, the `h2topic` paragraph designation turns into a `role = "new-topic"` attribute in the XML. The core problem is that we are using a build technique in ePublisher that is relatively easy to implement, but in the DocBook XSL build, this same technique is very difficult to implement.

In the DocBook build, you can easily chunk topics at any level in the XML tag hierarchy; we could start each new page at the `h4` level if we wanted to, just by setting a build parameter. To start new pages for some sections, and not for others, *at the same level in the tag hierarchy*, we are thinking that it would require some particularly gnarly custom XSLT coding.

Is this assumption correct?

Many thanks.
P.

Comment: you'll get better advice by including a small self-contained example of your inputs, required output, current output and current code. Good luck!

Comment: Possibly but you haven;t posted all the information. Starting new pages? Easy. Starting new page-sequences ... much harder. You have not correctly posed the question andd provided samples for people to understand.

Comment: This might help: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Chunking.html#ControllingChunks. There is also a special processing instruction: http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/pi/dbhtml_stop-chunking.html

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback. Apologies for not including any code yet -- I'm new to DocBook and don't quite understand it that well yet. The sagehill.net doc is very helpful, and I had no idea about that special `no-chunk`  processing instruction. (I think I need to study `XSL` ...)